# How can I show Modal box in react DOM?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I have a problem to show Modal box in DOM, I have 3 component: Navbar and Modal as child and Shopping as parent and I call Modal and Navbar in shopping, I want to show Modal box when I click at a span on Navbar, it doesn't work correctly, can you help me please?
Shopping Cod is:

```
class Shopping extends React.Component {
state = {
    products: {
        1: 0,
        2: 0,
        3: 0,
        4: 0,
        5: 0,
        6: 0,
    },
           addCounter: 0,
    purchased: false,
}

addProductHandler = (id, title, price) => {
    // Count
    const prevCount = this.state.addCounter
    const updatedCount = prevCount + 1
    this.setState({ totalPrice: newPrice, addCounter: updatedCount })
}

showModalHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ purchased: true })
}


render() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Navbar
                counter={this.state.addCounter}
                showModal={this.showModalHandler}
            />
            <Modal show={this.state.purchased} />
            <Control addProduct={this.addProductHandler} />
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

}

export default Shopping

Navbar Cod is:

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
return (
    <header className="header">
        <nav>
            <ul className="nav-items">
                <li className="nav-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a href="/">Products</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a href="/">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="#"><i className="fas fa-shopping-cart shopping-cart"></i></a>
        <span className="counter" onClick={() => props.showModal}>Orders: {props.counter}</span>
    </header>
)
```

}

export default Navbar

Modal Code is:

```
const Modal = (props) => {
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <div className="modal"
            style={{
                transform: props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                opacity: props.show ? '1' : '0',
            }}
        >
            <p>Hello Modal</p>
        </div>
    </Wrapper>
)
```

}

export default Modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showModal function is not called.
Call it

```
onClick={props.showModal}
```

or

```
onClick={() => props.showModal()}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using arrow function you have to call the respective function. You missed to add function brackets:

```
onClick={() => props.showModal()}
```

Or you can use either of these ways.

Using bind():

```
onClick={props.showModal.bind(this)}
```

or by passing reference:

```
onClick={props.showModal}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-khayyam-6dnyx?file=/src/Shopping.js)